# Is there any way to translate entire website using Microsoft Translator

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, angular-translate, microsoft-translator, azure-text-translation

I am having a website which is build on Angular 8 and Asp.Net Web Api. I am looking for a way to translate my own website in another language according the user selection.

I have looked in text translation api's but as we can translate certain text not the entire website contains.

For reference as the google translator work on one click it translate entire content on another language we are looking exactly that using Microsoft Translator. If you have any alternative suggestion that fits to our need please mention.

Answer (score 0):

You can put in a URL in bing.com/translator, and it produces a translated website. There's also built-in translation in Microsoft Edge [edge translation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/use-microsoft-translator-in-microsoft-edge-browser-4ad1c6cb-01a4-4227-be9d-a81e127fcb0b).
Or are you looking for an API?
[image]

Comment: Apparently [it is no longer possible](https://i.imgur.com/jr5cPp2.png). A URL is no longer recognized as something clickable. Found this question hoping there's some trick to it, but apparently it's just that bing removed capability of translating a website.

Comment: That's correct. You can use edge translation instead. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/use-microsoft-translator-in-microsoft-edge-browser-4ad1c6cb-01a4-4227-be9d-a81e127fcb0b

Comment: An "edge translation" won't function on a non-Edge browser.